# why char(13)+char(10) in for xml path('') does not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I use `char(13)+char(10)` in my queries it works, but when I use `char(13)+char(10)` in a query which has `for xml path('')` it does not work and instead of that I get this character `&#x0D;`
I think it is because of two `for xml path('')` although it may not.
what should I do?

there is a sample of my code:

```
select d.title+char(13)+char(10)+
(
   select c.title+char(13)+char(10)+
   (
      select a.title+b.title+char(13)+char(10)
      from tbl_one a
      inner join tbl_two b on a.id=b.one
      where a.id=aa.id
      for xml path('')
   )
   from tbl_one aa on 
   inner join tbl_three c on aa.id=c.one
   where aa.id=aaa.id
   for xml path('')
)
from tbl_four d
inner join tbl_one aaa on d.one=aaa.id
```

Comment: I recognise the title of this question from a short while ago, have you asked this again?

Comment: @DavidG yes because there were notifications that tell me my question is wrong and need code. I need to prepare the code so I could not edit that question cause that was not varifiable to ask, so I deleted till I manage my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a type directive for your xml output like so:

```
select d.title+char(13)+char(10)+
(
   select c.title+char(13)+char(10)+
   ((
      select a.title+b.title+char(13)+char(10)
      from tbl_one a
      inner join tbl_two b on a.id=b.one
      where a.id=aa.id
      for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
   )
   from tbl_one aa on 
   inner join tbl_three c on aa.id=c.one
   where aa.id=aaa.id
   for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
from tbl_four d
inner join tbl_one aaa on d.one=aaa.id
```

Reference:

- [Handling special characters with `for xml path('')` - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/)

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ETCRIW69262

```
select 'd'+char(13)+char(10)+
(
   select c+char(13)+char(10)+
   (
      select a+b+char(13)+char(10)
      from (values ('a','b')) x (a,b)
      for xml path ('')
   )
   from (values ('c'))x(c)
   for xml path (''))
```

returns:

```
d
c&#x0D;
ab&amp;#x0D;
```

and this version:

```
select 'd'+char(13)+char(10)+
(
   select c+char(13)+char(10)+
   ((
      select a+b+char(13)+char(10)
      from (values ('a','b')) x (a,b)
      for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
   )
   from (values ('c')) x (c)
   for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

returns:

```
d
c
ab
```

Comment: thanks man! I did not know about this type thing for xml path('').
also some one told me to use char(10)+char(10) instead of char(13)+char(10) and that worked too.
thank you very much. good luck :)